# Gronwall's Inequality Application

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, gronwall-type-inequality

Let say we have
$$ \frac{\partial |F|}{\partial t} \le K |F| + K \alpha^{2},\:\:\:\:\: t \in [t_{n}, t_{n+1}]$$
with $F(x, t_{n})=0$ and $t_{n+1}-t_{n}=\triangle t$. The above is the same thing as
$$ \frac{\partial (|F| + \alpha^{2})}{\partial t} \le K ( |F| + \alpha^{2})$$

and by Gronwall's inequality we must have that $|F|$ is bounded by the solution of
$$\frac{\partial (|f| + \alpha^{2})}{\partial t} = K ( |f| + \alpha^{2})$$

which is $$ |f|+\alpha^{2} = g(x)e^{Kt}$$

but $|f(x,t_{n})|=0$ which means $\alpha^{2} = g(x)e^{Kt_{n}}$. So by Gronwall's inequality we have

$$ |F| \le \alpha^{2} e^{K(t-t_{n})} - \alpha^{2}$$

but why does the author of a paper mentioned
$$ |F| \le K_{\alpha} \triangle t $$
where $K_{\alpha}$ is some constant depending on $\alpha>0$?

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess without more information, but I suppose that only small time intervals $\Delta t$ are considered. Indeed, if $\Delta t\leq C$, then the right hand side of the second last equation of your question can be rewritten as follows:
$$\alpha^2\left(e^{K(t-t_n)}-1\right)=\alpha^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{K^k(t-t_n)^k}{k!}\right)=\alpha^2K(t-t_n)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{K^{k}(t-t_n)^k}{(k+1)!}\right)\leq\alpha^2K\Delta t\, e^{CK}.$$

Comment: The author of the paper mentioned that $K_{\alpha}$ "depends on $\alpha$ (and also perhaps something else), be we want to highlight $\alpha$ dependancy".